# Unable to git pull Wordpress' folders and sub folders from OpenShift repo using Git

Tags: wordpress, git, openshift

I created a wordpress app hosted on Openshift from the CLI. 
 
I'm on a Win7 PC. 

 
After that I made several changes to my Wordpress site from the Wordpress Admin Dashboard. Now I want to pull the whole app to my local machine. 
 
I did a git pull which fetched the only folders and files sans the actual wordpress app. 
 
When I tried to run it using a WAMP, there's no wordpress site to be started. When I again ran

> git pull

The message I get is

> Already up-to-date

I'm a rookie and I want to make changes to my wordpress site locally and then push them to the server. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

if you are installing plugins & themes via the wordpress admin, they are not in git, they are installed in your $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR, and are saved there outside of git, you can see in this script where it does the symlinks into your wordpress installation: https://github.com/openshift/wordpress-example/blob/master/.openshift/action_hooks/deploy

If you want those in git also, you would need to modify that script to remove the symlinks, and then put your plugins & themes in git and do a push.

Comment: To modify the script, I need to have the source files on my local machine, right? And I'm unable to take a pull of the wordpress files from the server.

Comment: Then you already have the files you need.  Look in your .openshift folder (you may have to turn on viewing hidden files in your operating system)

Comment: Yes, the .openshift folder is there, but there are no wordpress files in it. How do I get those files from the server?

Comment: You would need to ssh into your gear, package up the files (that should be in your app-root/data directory) and then download them to your computer.